# What is the root of an absolute path when importing a module in typescript?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, webpack, typescript1.8

I'm developing an app in typescript (in Visual Studio 2015) and have this basic file structure:

```
Solution
    AppProject
        Scripts
            framework
                Utils.ts
            app
                SomeApp.ts
        tsconfig.json
```

Now within the app modules, I would like to reference the framework modules with an absolute path, so I would do something like this:

```
import { Utils } from '/Scripts/framework/Utils'
```

However **this doesn't work**.
I'm getting the red squiggly line and a "*Cannot find module '/Scripts/framework/Utils'*"

I works fine when doing a relative path, but the app is obviously more complex than what is shown, and I don't want to deal with stepping out multiple levels for my relative path.

I am using typescript 1.8 with the node module resolution strategy.
And webpack to compile and bundle it, if that matters

Comment: Have you went through the [Module Resolution section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) of the docs?

Comment: Yes, the documentation doesn't seem to describe how absolute paths are used. Only relative and non-relative

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Absolute paths & require()](https://coderwall.com/p/th6ssq/absolute-paths-require)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on that in the docs. So I traced the file system accesses performed by the compiler (TypeScript 2.5.2) when trying to resolve an import of an absolute path.

The result is that **`/` always refers to the file system root**. Regardless of `compilerOptions` like `rootDir`, `rootDirs` or `baseUrl`.

Comment: Support was added for leading slash in this PR -> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19318

Comment: I think #19318 was a mistyping and leading slashes are solved by this. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13730 Pull: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27980