# Import module from root path in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript2.1, typescript2.2

Let's suppose I've a project, and its main source directory is:

```
C:\product\src
```

Based on this directory, every import path would be relative to it. I.e., suppose:

```
// Current script: C:\product\src\com\name\product\blah.ts

import { thing } from '/com/name/product/thing';
```

same as:

```
// Current script: C:\product\src\com\name\product\blah.ts

import { thing } from '../../../com/name/product/thing';
```

My entry compilation file would be at:

```
C:\product\src
```

for instance. So, is there a way to specify this such entry path (`C:\product\src`, for example) at the compiler options? I need to specify this in the `tsconfig.json` file, because I'll use webpack.

I've tried my above example, but TypeScript says the requested module cannot be found:

```
// Current script: A.ts

import { B } from '/com/B';


// Current script: B.ts

export const B = 0;
```

My tsconfig.json file (inside another project, but both similiar):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "target": "ES6"
    },

    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `C:\product\src` + `../../../com/name/product/thing` is not `C:\product\src\com\name\product\blah.ts`. Am I missing something? You want disallow `..`ing up a certain root directory?

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer The `// C:\product\src\com\name\product\blah.ts` comment means that the following script with import declaration is the blah.ts file, it's not related to the import path. Sry! Not sure what you meant by `..`, I'm not very good at English :/.

Comment: Please post your tsconfig.json

Comment: @TeddySterne Added.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

(Re-posting my answer to avoid puppy-socket.)

Using the [`compilerOptions.baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) property I was able to do the below import. This allowed me to have a complete root-to-expected-path, which helps my code maintainance, and works in any file, independently of the current folder. The below examples will have the src folder of my project as the modules root.

Important advice: this baseUrl property doesn't affect the entry webpack file (at least for me?), so separate a main file inside the src folder with this example, and run it from the entry (i.e., `import { Main } from './src/Main'; new Main;`), only once.

```
// browser: directory inside src;
//   * net: A TS file.
import { URLRequest } from 'browser/net';
```

**tsconfig.json** example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "target": "ES6"
    },

    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

However, it won't directly work with webpack. The same thing must be done at the webpack options. This is how it worked in webpack 2:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  , resolve: {
      ...
      , modules: [ path.join(__dirname, './src') ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, answer but don't forget to also put node_modules in there.

Comment: I found the includes section unnecessary and will even attempt to compile what's in node_modules. I set baseUrl, rootDir, ouputDir in tsconfig. In webpack I added node_modules as @EyalPerry pointed out. Seems to be working great.

Comment: I'm using `create-react-app` and setting only `baseUrl` was sufficient. Thanks! 

Answer (score 21):

I needed to set both `baseUrl` and `rootDir` to point to my src folder in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "rootDir": "./src",
  ...
}
```

I could then import .tsx files without needing a prefixed '/' or a relative path.

e.g.
`import BreadCrumb from 'components/BreadCrumb'`

Comment: This works in vscode linting, and `tsc` will build it fine, but then I get `module not found` when I try to run the compiled code.

Comment: For me I only had to provide a `baseUrl`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your development server for this to work 

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript imports use `/` at the start of a path to denote the root directory. To import a file relative to your current file either leave off the initial slash or use `./`.

```
// Current script: C:\product\src\com\name\product\blah.ts
import { thing } from './com/name/product/thing';
```

By default the TypeScript compiler assumes the root of the project is the same as the location of your tsconfig.json.

You can specify a new root by specifying the `rootDir` property of the `compilerOptions` property in the tsconfig.

For a list of all available property settings consult the tsconfig definition found [here](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig).

Comment: Thanks for the assumption of the root directory, however I can't still import a file relative to its root, as TypeScript continues saying that the import module doesn't exist/can't be found. I've tried with and without slash, but nothing, same with `./`.

Comment: Try switching `module` to `node`

Comment: **`/` always refers to the file system root.** [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229294/380229)

Answer (score 4):

**Just for record**

If you want use absolute import from your project, Do not use `/`  as prefix, such as `/src/config/cfg`, just use as `src/config/cfg`

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229294/7529562 pointed, `/` stand for **System root**,

`tsc` will complain `cannot find module`

Comment: This isn't true. Support was added in 2017 -> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19318

Comment: To get a path like `src/config/cfg` to work for me I had to provide a `baseUrl` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

In your TS config, set

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  …
  "moduleResolution": "bundler",
}
```

You can then remove the “.ts” extension from the import statement.

Answer (score -5):

Solution for your import statement in **thing.ts** will be

```
import {} './product/blah'
```

and your project structure might be as

[image]

### Other Possible options with explanation

---

I have the following application structure and I place it in

**`C:\\Users\\(username)\\Documents\firstAngular2App`**

as in the screenshot.

[image]

I am importing components to the app.module.ts as

1. **./** will show the current folder (app)

   ```
   import { } from './';
   ```

[image]

2. **../** will refer to the root folder (firstAngular2App-master)

   ```
   import { } from '../';
   ```

[image]

3. **../../** will refer to the root folder (Documents folder)

   ```
   import { } from '../../';
   ```

[image]

4. **../app/** refers to the app folder but it is referred from the root(firstAngular2App)

   ```
   import {} from '../app/';
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, however that's not broadly exactly what I was looking for. I know I can use the `..` and `./` tokens for relative-importing, there's yet an example in my question.

Comment: what is that you were looking for

Comment: I'm trying to avoid deep-relative paths, I want to specify a relative path from the project root, not by the current file root. For example, my root would now be the src folder. Suppose I've a file `src/blah/Class.ts`, in which `import { Export } from 'export'` would refer to `src/Export.ts`. I don't want to depend on `..` or `./` tokens, unfortunately they made me almost create a new programming language to replace TypeScript, they made my code maintainance ugly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135538/discussion-between-aravind-and-handoncloud).