# Webpack expose local module

Tags: webpack

If I have the following module:

```
// ./lib/foo.js
const foo = 'hello';
export default foo
```

And I want to expose it as a global. I have it loaded into my vendor entry in the webpack config:

```
entry: {
  vendor: [..., './lib/foo']
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    './lib/foo': 'foo'
  })
]
```

Or:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve('./lib/foo'), loader: 'expose?foo' }
  ],
}
```

And in both variants tried with `window.` prefix too. But it's not getting exposed. Have tried adding a `require('./lib/foo')` in my apps entry file as the docs for [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) seem to suggest that is necessary.

Comment: is this part of a vendor module that you want to use in another area or is this a JS library that you are building?

Comment: I don't know how to expose modules globally, but you may get an approximation using require. Check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42123382#42195257), it's about importing modules in TypeScript, over the root path, without using `..`, `./`, etc. But it's related to webpack in the same time.

Comment: Am not sure what the end goal is : Assuming the end goal is to build and expose a JS library that you want to use, I guess you may try exposing foo as a library . Here is an example in the docs provided : https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html This is how I did it for mine. Am not sure about the expose-loader plugin
If you want to just expose one particular module, then am not sure.

Comment: It's a module that I want to expose globally so that I don't have to import it everywhere, basically it's an extension of `fetch` to add some custom functionality and I would like it to be available at `window.customFetch`. I guess I'm just been lazy by wanting it to be a global

Comment: Look into library targets. You can bundle so that you get a global.