# File Pathing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a folder that looks like

Main > models > file1.ejs

|

|> routes > file2.ejs

Two require file1 from file2 the code is const variable = require("../models/file1.ejs)
Let's say I do not want to require the model relatively, why does
const variable = require("/models/file1.ejs") not work.

Isnt "/" meaning to start at the root directory?

If we have an extensive nest of folders within another, how can we avoid doing "../../../../" in our file pathing?

Additionally, why does a code in JS that looks like Comment = require("./models/comment")
work but does not work when you do Comment = require("models/comment")

Or something in ejs that looks like <%- include("partials/header") %>
<%- include("/partials/header") %> does not work.

Is there anyway to always start from the root directory during pathing? Starting with "/" seems to end up causing an error when its suppose to make my pathing start from the root directory.

Comment: If you are going to specify file paths relatively you have to give many .. and / if you are in a different folder, or you can also give it absolute path, then you have to start from the root, where in your case /models is not at the root.

Comment: @Tick20 Can you show me what it would look like to use the absolutely path and include models in it? Sorry I'm new to coding.

Comment: I have posted as the answer

Comment: You do not have the period in your require statement const variable = require("./models/file1.ejs")

Comment: @Brian, if any of the answers below solved your issue, please feel free to accept it as an answer, you can also gives upvotes if you feel it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example consider the below code,

```
var filename = "file1.ejs"; 
var fullpath = __dirname + "/models/" + filename;
```

read the docs about __dirname [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

This is how you can provide the absolute path, where the __dirname will provide you with the path until the current working directory.

Where as relative paths work as below,

For example, if you trying to access file `file1.ejs` which is inside `models` directory from other file `file2.ejs` which is inside directory `models2` where the `models2` directory is also inside `models` then you may provide the relative path,

ie, the folder structure is as follows,

```
basePath/models/file1.ejs   
basePath/models/models2/file2.ejs
```

and access file1.ejs from file2.ejs as below,

```
var path = '../file1.ejs'  // going one folder back and getting inside parent models directory where the file1.ejs resides
```

Comment: better to use `path` module. `const path = require('path');  const fullPath = path.join(__dirname,'models','<filename>')`.

Answer (score 0):

> Isnt "/" meaning to start at the root directory?

No. "/" refers to your existing file directory.

> Additionally, why does a code in JS that looks like Comment = require("./models/comment") work but does not work when you do Comment = require("models/comment")

"/" is how node differentiates if they should pick up locally or somewhere in your installed modules. Imagine you have `Express` installed in your project and you have a file `express.js`. Then `require('./express')` will import your local file but `require('express')` will import the installed library instead.

> If we have an extensive nest of folders within another, how can we avoid doing "../../../../" in our file pathing?

I believe you will need Babel. I haven't found any good sample on the web, but here are some useful materials.

Side note, I have worked on node project with related setup, but the development experience was awful as my editor couldn't pick up the resolved path and was struggling with auto-complete and intellisense. (but I personally believe the setup way was wrong or depreciated).

Resources:

- [Import module from root path in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123382/import-module-from-root-path-in-typescript)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/