# Webpack and TypeScript Global Variables / Global Functions

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, global-variables

I am using Webpack with TypeScript, HTML, and SCSS to create a project. I am trying to create a single page application that uses a router that is in a root folder of the project `/framework/` and all of my source code is in the `/src/` directory. However when I go into sub folders (e.g. `/src/pages/home/index.ts`) I would prefer if I didn't have to go `import * as framework from '../../../framework/';` in every page. I have looked at other solutions on StackOverflow and none of them seem to work. I have tried

```
// File: /webpack.dev.config.js

resolve: {
        alias: {
            framework: path.resolve(__dirname, './framework') // <-- When you build or restart dev-server, you'll get an error if the path to your utils.js file is incorrect.
        }
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            framework: [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'framework')), 'framework']
        })
    ],
```

and it didn't work. I have also tried

```
// File: /src/index.ts

const path = require('path');
global.fw = String(path.resolve(__dirname, "framework"));
```

in type script and it throws me an error `fs: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)`

Is there someway I can say `import * as framework from '@framework';` or `import * as framework from '@framework/main';` or something along those lines? Or even like a global variable that I can use? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, after searching for more answers I stumbled upon this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151895/18547633), I tried it our and it worked! This is the answer that I found to work.

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  // ...
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "rootDir": "./",
  // ...
}
```